# Как сделать буквы "е" и "ё" разными в купонах woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce считает купоны "алёша" и "алеша" идентичными. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать их разными?

Comment: Изменить COLLATION поля, хранящего это значение. Изменить COLLATION соединения.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, буду пробовать